# textField user input error - cocoa

Tags: cocoa

i create a very simple cocoa app for macOs.

You put in a textfield area something and when you press the ok button the app is opening your default browser , going to a specific webpage and searching with the value that the user gave.

My problem is when i am trying to search with 2 words the app stop working.
With one word everything is ok.

```
import Cocoa
```

class PanelViewContoler: NSViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var quitBtn: NSButton!

@IBOutlet weak var search: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet weak var okBtn: NSButton!


class func loadFromNib()-> PanelViewContoler{
    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    return storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "PanelViewContoler") as!
    PanelViewContoler
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}
@IBAction func ok(_ sender: Any) {

    print("oksss")

    let rpStartURL =  "https://xxxxxx/communities/service/html/mycommunities?search="
    let searchString = rpStartURL + search.stringValue
    print(search.stringValue)
    let searchURL = NSURL(string: searchString)

    NSWorkspace.shared().open(searchURL as! URL)

}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Actually what i need is if at the string is space to be replaced with +.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find it.

search.stringValue.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+").

Comment: The is not the point (at least not the whole point...). Every character that isn't a letter or a number may cause the same behavior in your app. You need to encode `search.stringValue` with percent encoding.